# Tailwind animation ease

Tags: tailwind-css

I try to put a simple transition on an after pseudo element in Tailwind.
The css is:

.button::after {
transition: 0.5s all ease
}

I tried:

```
class="after:transition after:ease after:duration-500"
```

But nothing. I see that after:ease doesn't work, but how do I go about this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added only `ease` as the class. But tailwind have no class named `ease`. So you have to update your class `ease` with one of the following classes:

- ease-in
- ease-out
- ease-in-out
- ease-linear

For more information please refer to [Official Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-timing-function#controlling-the-easing-curve)

Comment: I get an error when I use ease-linear in PhpStorm: mismatched property.

Comment: Can you share your code that you have putted?

Comment: And it's just an css class it should not give an error. I think you know we can use any thing randomly as class. But stills if it gives an error you can either neglect it or use other ease class from the other 3

Comment: And you can see in the Internet that there was a recent bug report on the PHPStom and WEBStom that there tailwind plugin is not it compatible with the new version of the taildwindcss. So it gives you a error 

Comment: So I'll recommend you to use the `ease-in` or `ease-out` or `ease-in-out`

Answer (score 2):

If you use Tailwind 3.x you can use arbitrary values:

```html
<div class="after:transition after:ease-[ease] after:duration-500"></div>
```

[Tailwind arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values)

Answer (score 0):

Define transition, duration and ease (-in,out, etc.) Take a look to this class:

```html
 <div
  class="transition-opacity 
   duration-500 
   ease-out opacity-100 hover:opacity-0 
   bg-black text-white font-bold p-10 px-4 h-screen">
  Bye Bye
 </div>
```

**working example**
https://play.tailwindcss.com/160JJfEXJe